# Enable error reporting for a DDNS address

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to enable php error reporting only for my own IP. My IP changes but I have a DDNS (dynamic DNS) address which points to my actual IP. This solution is not for productional usage. I just want to be able to debug a remote server without providing the errors to everybody in the internet.

Idea was to use some kind of `<If...>` directive where I check if the IP is my DDNS IP or to use a `RewriteRule`. For the `RewriteRules` I need to input a real IP and no DDNS domain. The reverse lookup for the domain will fail too, because I cannot control the rDNS.

Any ideas what I can try?

Comment: @Charles NO I mean DDNS = Dynamic DNS not plain DNS!

Comment: DNS is DNS is DNS.  The fact that it's dynamic has no bearing on the actual question being asked.  In fact, this isn't really even a DNS question at all, it's a question about how to handle hostnames sanely instead of IPs in Apache...

Comment: For DDNS are some other rules IMHO. The TTL is much less, the A record changes *often* and the reverse DNS is commonly not under the control. The two of that three points are a problem is my question. Do you dissagree with me?

Answer (score 0):

Why not in PHP ?

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = 'your ip') {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
}
```

**Edit:**
If you want to do something with the hostname attached to that IP address, just add [gethostbyaddr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) or [gethostbyname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) in your if-statement. (which one of the two you want to use depends if you want to check on IP or on hostname)

```
if(gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == 'my hostname') { .. same code }
```

Comment: the problem is that "your ip" isn't known. The OP has a DDNS hostname that points towards the ip, but it the ip itself changes. So if you can do a `$ip = getIpFromHostname($hisDDNS);`, then this is workable, but the question is a bit how to get this done?

Comment: I would like to have this somewhere in the server configuration. So I don't need to modify any php applications running on that server. The part about `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` won't work due I cannot mannage this string.